# How do I compile the linux kernel version 3.16.1 to run in Slackware 14.1?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, slackware

Could someone teach me or give me some tutorial? How do I compile the linux kernel version 3.16.1 to run in Slackware 14.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please keep in mind that not using the kernel distributed with Slackware may break your system.**

Apart of that, compiling the official kernel is a difficult task and takes its time. You can learn about how to compile your own or the official linux kernel on Kernelnewbies.org.

Related:

- http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild
- https://www.kernel.org

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I compiled the kernel 3.16.1 and it worked. I just removed the support for amd processors because my processor is intel, worked smoothly, I will study how further customize the kernel.